# Pass DOM element into angular scope on function

Tags: angularjs

If I have an anchor:

```
<a ng-href="{{model.getUrl(<?>)}}" data-network="twitter">test</a>
```

And a scope function that returns a string (it does not run on a click event):

```
$scope.model.getUrl = function(element){
    // How can i get access to the data-network attribute
    switch(element.dataNetwork){
        case "twitter":
        break;
    }
}
```

How can i get access to the data-network attribute from within this free running function?

**Note:**

The reason i haven't passed in a string, is because data-network needs to be there for other non angular and angular things happening in the page. So i thought i'd hijack it and use it as well rather than re-define a string just so angular can have at it.

Comment: Couldn't you just pass the exact value of `data-network` attribute as a parameter to your function ?

Comment: I can, but this data-network is used by 2 other contexts. So i thought it'd be nice to avoid passing in a string of the network AND also having the data-network there too (which is used for other things)

Comment: Then just remove `data-network` attribute and just pass the desired value as a parameter each time. This way you'll keep your template complexity at low levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a directive of type `A` something like `setUrl`

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('setUrl', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        switch(attrs.network){
          case "twitter":
          break;
        }

        // If you need to set the ng-href you can use attrs.$set
        attrs.$set('ng-href', '/your/path/');
      }
    }
  });
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a set-url data-network="twitter">Twitter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control on this template, you should have:

```
<a ng-href="{{model.getUrl(type)}}" data-network="{{type}}">test</a>
```

and define `type` in controller.

If `type` do not change you can use one-time binding:

```
<a ng-href="{{::model.getUrl(type)}}" data-network="{{::type}}">test</a>
```